# Flutter - Scrollable Stack

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So, I have a design with 4 major components.

- Image Carousel
- Information Box
- Ming Button
- Back Button

[image: design]

I have arranged all of them in a stack & now I want the whole stack to scroll upwards. To clarify all the elements should scroll just like in a column. If I add a `SingleChildScrollView` above stack it give me this error
`'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 599 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.`

This is the current code of the stack that I have.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: imageCarousel(),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: imageHeight - 20,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: informationBox(
          showMingButton: showMingButton),
    ),
    if (showMingButton)
      Positioned(
        top: imageHeight - 50,
        width: deviceWidth * 1,
        child: mingButton(),
      ),
    Positioned(
      top: 10,
      right: 20,
      child: AnimatedBackButton(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        buttonWidth: 50,
        buttonHeight: 50,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Now, I did manage to get the output that I wanted, but it was by wrapping the whole stack in a SizedBox and by giving it a fixed height, but that defeats my purpose & it either leaves a lot of empty space at the bottom or the informationBox gets clipped.

Some info about the child widgets:

- The `Image Carousel` has a fixed height & is basically a pagebuilder
- The `Ming Button` & the `back button` are simple elevated button
- The `informationBox` is a complex widget with multiple rows & columns in it, but I have ensured that there is nothing there which can force it to take an infinite height/width.

Please do let me know how can I solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: as you are using only Positioned in the stack, it cannot define it's height properly.
check out the useful answers of this thread, it might give you a clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359662/how-to-make-stack-layout-scroll-able-using-singlechildscrollview

Comment: @Csisanyi I already tried everything from this thread. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Am I right if I think your problem is not knowing the exact height of the information box?
Everything else seems to be static. I think if you want to stay with your current implementation, you need to find a reliable way to predict the size of infobox and use a SizedBox with the max height your data on the screen can make up .
I wouldn't necessarily wrap your current code in the sizedBox, but just add it as the first element. Stack will layout it's height based on it's largest child if I'm correct.

Comment: @Csisanyi, you are correct. Only the information box will have a dynamic height. Rest all the components have a static height. But the problem is that we can't calculate the height of the information box as it will depend on the data we receive from the server. That data can be more or less depending on each user.

Comment: It's tricky. First thing on my mind would be adding a limit to the mystory info or simply check the size of it before rendering.
I guess you get the info from some db?

Comment: @Csisanyi I already tried that. If I just render all the information and from some trial & error get he max height informationBox can have, even then if there is some information missing then empty space will be left. I have tried this too & there was a lot of empty space left at the bottom & that just doesn't look good.